# Relational to Relational Field in Odoo ERP

Tags: odoo

I'am really not sure if it is silly but raising concern here as iam facing issue.

I want to know how to achieve two step relational field i.e., relational to relational field.

Ex., I have city domain which internally referring to state and state domain internally refers to country domain.

In city view, i am trying to show both state and country details. I can easily get state details by using relational field to state_id.

But when i tried to fetch country details from city domain in the same way , data is not retrieved.

Please let me know if any one knows this. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

you need two relational field:

```
class a(models.Model):
    _name = 'city'
    city = fields.Many2one('state')
    state = fields.Many2one('country',related=city.country)
class b(models.Model):
    _name = 'state'
    country = fields.Many2one('country')
class c(models.Model):
    _name = 'country'
```

so state will be related to state -> country